# Best method for repeated searches on large list of dicts

Tags: python, postgresql, dictionary

Let's say I have a function that returns 1000 records from a postgres database as a list of dicts that looks like this (but much bigger):

```
[ {"thing_id" : 245, "thing_title" : "Thing title", "thing_url": "thing-url"},
  {"thing_id" : 459, "thing_title" : "Thing title II", "thing_url": "thing-url/2"}]
```

I have a process that requires around 600 individual searches on this list for the right dict based on a given unique `thing_id`. Rather than iterating through the entire list each time, wouldn't it be more efficient to create a dict of dicts, making the `thing_id` for each dict a key, like this:

```
{245 : {"thing_id" : 245, "thing_title" : "Thing title", "thing_url": "thing-url"},
 459 : {"thing_id" : 459, "thing_title" : "Thing title II", "thing_url": "thing-url/2"}}
```

If so, is there a preferred way of doing this? Obviously I could build the dict by iterating through the list. But was wondering if there are any built in methods for this. If not, what is the preferred way of going about this? Also, is there a better way of repeatedly retrieving data from the same large set of records than what I am proposing here, please let me know.

**UPDATE**: Ended up going with dict comprehension:

```
data = {row["thing_id"]: row for row in rows}
```

where rows is the result from my db query with a psycopg2.extras.DictCursor. Building the dict is fast enough and the lookups are very fast.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is a string that concatenates various things from the dict. As my main concern is doing repeated lookups on the same dataset and within different use cases, I am deliberately not emphasizing what I am doing with the data. Basically I want to return the dicts I need, based on their thing_ids, as efficiently as possible.

Comment: And what exactly is that string? Can you give a sample of your expected output? That would help me and other give you a solution that fits your need.

Comment: Assume that my input is a thing_id and my output is a thing_url. I want the fastest way to make about 600 of that kind of retrieval from the same list of dicts. I have a thing_id, I want to get the dict that thing_id is in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pandas DataFrame structure for multi column indexing:

```
>>> result = [
        {"thing_id" : 245, "thing_title" : "Thing title", "thing_url": "thing-url"},
        {"thing_id" : 459, "thing_title" : "Thing title II", "thing_url": "thing-url/2"}
    ]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(result)
>>> df.set_index('thing_id', inplace=True)
>>> df.sort_index(inplace=True)
>>> df
             thing_title    thing_url
thing_id                             
245          Thing title    thing-url
459       Thing title II  thing-url/2
>>> df.loc[459, 'thing_title']
'Thing title II'
```

Comment: hmm, was hoping not to have to install anything.

Comment: It's just a suggestion since it's highly optimized for large tabular datasets, and you said: "Also, if there is a better way of repeatedly retrieving data from the same large set of records than what I am proposing here, please let me know."

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out if I don't find something built-in that serves my requirements as well.

Comment: If you decide on using it, it has an optimized version of loading  data directly from the database, so you don't have to rearrange it: `df = pd.io.sql.read_sql('SELECT ... FROM ...', db_connection)`

Comment: hm, that is tantalizing.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [ {"thing_id" : 245, "thing_title" : "Thing title", "thing_url": "thing-url"}, {"thing_id" : 459, "thing_title" : "Thing title II", "thing_url": "thing-url/2"}]
c = [b.values()[1] for b in a]
```